# Проверка выхода за пределы вектора

Tags: c++, vector

У меня есть вектор с элементами. Мне нужно выводить по три элемента. Если на пример, у меня в есть 5 элементов, сначало нужно вывести 3 а потом 2, но в цикле в формуле (pageNumber - 1) * 3 + 2 стоит +2, то есть должно выводиться 3 элемента, а затем еще 3. Как мне сделать проверку, не вышел ли я за пределы вектора ?

```
int reviewAllEvents(const User &user, vector<Event> &events)
{
    system("CLS");

    int pageNumber = 0;

    for (int i = (pageNumber - 1) * 3; i <= (pageNumber - 1) * 3 + 2; i++)
    {
        cout << events[i].getTitle() << endl;
        cout << events[i].getShortPlot() << endl;
        cout << events[i].getDate() << events[i].getAuthor() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что этот бредовый код означает? Где здесь три элемента, которые выводятся? Почему индекс вектора отрицательное число?!

Comment: `i = [-3, -1]` "не вышел ли я за пределы вектора?" Вышел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте проверку

```
if (i < 0 || i >= events.size()) break;
```